# Symfony : Access-Control-Allow-Origin ('security.token_storage)

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I work with Symfony and I try to get the user id from another website (ajax). But it does not works !

I have this error in my browser :

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

My code is :

```
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
/* That does not works and returns : 'NOOOO !!!' but, no error */
if($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_USER'))
{
    $usertosend = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    $id = $usertosend->getId();
    $response->setData(array('user'=>$id));
}
else
{
    $response->setData(array('user'=>'NOOOO !!!'));
}
/* That works :*/ 
$usertosend = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
/* That does not works and returns : Access-Control-Allow-Origin error*/
$id = $usertosend->getId();
```

As soon as I use a getter of the user, there is an error.
If I don't use the getter, there is no error.
There is no problem with the origin domain.

---

Ok, The problem came from the cookies. So I add these headers :

```
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'get');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, *');
```

And I add this mention in my ajax method :

```
xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
```

---

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'http://myurl.com',
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    success: function(user){
    alert(user.user);
}
```

I hope, it will help next users.
Thanks for your help :)
See you

Answer (score 0):

You can use NelmioCorsBundle in your symfony project for adding headers CORS in they response of your application.

This is a very simple and quickly installation. This is a standard bundle for construct a symfony API Rest Application which called with external application.

[NelmioCorsBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle)

Comment: Thanks for your help. :) It doen't work :( The problem come from the User. If I use a getter of the user, the error happens. maybe, I have to allow the origin for the user token storage, I don't know :(